# What makes a file into a folder?

Tags: java, file, filesystems, directory

What is the (file system specific) difference between a file and a folder?

Why are different methods in `java.nio.file.Files` required to create the one or the other? `createDirectory(..)` and `createFile(..)`. Both use `Path` as a handle / identifier for the file system object.

Should I think of something special while creating one or the other as of failure cases (besides using different methods for creating the one or the other) ?

For the creation of a file or folder, if there is already a file or folder with the same name, this is a failure case. If it is going to be  an r/w file or folder, in the folder case writable means files may be created in it and in the file case it means writing bytes to it - is there a difference how to check this ?

If actually there is no difference for the failure cases, I would like to abstract away a custom `FileSystemObject` and treat them all the same.

Comment: Please do some homework on 1st, It's basic in computer that difference between file and folder.

Comment: @Longpoke, Can you Enplane more what you saying?

Comment: First create a file in your current OS. Then, create a new file with same name that previous file. See what happens. Do the same with folder/directory. Now, **make a test using Java code** and **see what happens**. You must assume that the file/folder creation are in the same path (otherwise the exercise won't make sense).

Comment: hmm ok. I don't know if that will enlighten me but thanks. I would have liked to know if there is an fundamental difference actually.

Comment: You can ask this to your Operating Systems teacher (when you study the course of course).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza why would you not just want to answer it instead?

Comment: Because that's not a programming question.

Comment: oh ok. I thought, because I was sitting here with pen and paper and drawing decision trees to figure out the real procedure to create reliably files and folders with java, that was one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.

In the most common operating systems (Windows, Linux, etc.), a folder can contain things. Those things have names. Each thing can either be a file or a directory.

So you might have some folder that has the following:

```
  a
  b
d c
d d
```

`a` and `b` are files. `c` and `d` are folders. `a` and `b` can only contain binary data. But `c` and `d` can contain other files/folders.

For example `c` might look like this:

```
  afile
  anotherfile
d morestuff
d stuff
```

This allows you to make a hierarchy as deep as you want, structured however you want. It is a very basic example of a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) data structure. It's useful to choose whether you're making a file or folder since files and folders are separate types of things. A filesystem could have files that are also folders, but I've never seen any filesystem like that. In Windows/Linux for example if you make a file, you can't use it as a folder, you can only change the contents of the file (which is just arbitrary binary data).