# create file, exception cases in java

Tags: java, exception, filesystems, directory, createfile

In Java (newer version) and windows xp (ntfs):

1 - Existing file f, Files.createFile(Paths.get(f)) :
`FileAlreadyExistsException`

2 - Existing file f, Files.createDirectory(Paths.get(f)) : 
`FileAlreadyExistsException`

3 - Existing folder fo, Files.createDirectory(Paths.get(fo)) : 
`FileAlreadyExistsException`

4 - Existing folder fo, Files.createFile(Paths.get(fo)) :
`AccessDeniedException`

Why is the last one different?

Linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540191/what-makes-a-file-into-a-folder) question, what is the conceptual difference ?

Doesn't it mean for a folder or a file the same when they are "writable". Or a locked file or folder, you can't access the content.

I think actually of a folder as a file with a contents list. You can open it actually with vim. So in the end, why are all filesystem elements which contain binary or textual data. This two fold policy is making stuff complicated. In this respect I actually do like the unix philosophy of files. It doesn't make a difference between folders, files and device files (special files).

And as hierarchical filesystem structure is actually the gof4 composite pattern I think I'm right, it is abstracting away a "Filesystemelement" as well.

Why is Java complicating things here?

Comment: You need write / create permission there I guess, or even read permission to that path.

Answer (score 1):

**aha, the reason is just there existing a folder(not a file), 
so the exception type mustn't be FileAlreadyExistsException.**

Comment: The third case then would have also not be "FileAlreadyExistsException" since it is a folder, also